# multiplie definition of class function in 2 translation units

Tags: c++, cmake

i am trying to port my code from linux to windows and i am having linkage  to a class functions .

i tried the following solution to set those functions as inline and still having  , i tried using #pragma once and still issue was not solved .

this is my header file PciResources.h

all the bellow functions are declared in PciResources.cpp

```
#ifndef PCI_RESOURCES_H_
#define PCI_RESOURCES_H_
#include <HostCliAgent.h>
#include "PciCrspaceFactory.h"
#include "PciConfigurationSpaceAgent.h"
class PciResources {
public:

void addPciConfigurationSpaceAgent(pPciConfigurationSpaceAgent pci_configuration_space_agent);
void addHostCliAgent(pHostCliAgent hostCliAgent);
void addPciCrspaceAgent(pCRPci pciCrspace);

pPciConfigurationSpaceAgent getPciConfigurationSpaceAgent();
pHostCliAgent getHostCliAgent();
pCRPci getPciCrspace();

bool hasCrspace();
bool hasConfigurationSpaceAgent();
bool hasHostCliAgent();

private:
pCRPci                      _pci_crspace;
pPciConfigurationSpaceAgent _pci_configuration_space_agent;
pHostCliAgent               _host_cli_agent;
};
typedef shared_ptr<PciResources>    pPciResources;
#endif /* PCI_RESOURCES_H_ */
```

i am getting the following linkage  from other translation unit :

```
pci_resources/libpci_resources.a(PciResources.cpp.obj): In function `PciResources::getPciConfigurationSpaceAgent()':
Z:/pci_resources/src/PciResources.cpp:15: multiple definition of `PciResources::getPciConfigurationSpaceAgent()'
pci_test/libpci_test.dll.a(d001513.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
pci_resources/libpci_resources.a(PciResources.cpp.obj): In function `PciResources::getHostCliAgent()':
Z:/pci_resources/src/PciResources.cpp:23: multiple definition of `PciResources::getHostCliAgent()'
pci_test/libpci_test.dll.a(d001508.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
pci_resources/libpci_resources.a(PciResources.cpp.obj): In function `PciResources::getPciCrspace()':
Z:/pci_resources/src/PciResources.cpp:37: multiple definition of `PciResources::getPciCrspace()'
pci_test/libpci_test.dll.a(d001506.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
pci_resources/libpci_resources.a(PciResources.cpp.obj): In function `PciResources::hasCrspace()':
Z:/pci_resources/src/PciResources.cpp:44: multiple definition of `PciResources::hasCrspace()'
pci_test/libpci_test.dll.a(d001505.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
pci_resources/libpci_resources.a(PciResources.cpp.obj): In function `PciResources::hasConfigurationSpaceAgent()':
Z:/pci_resources/src/PciResources.cpp:48: multiple definition of `PciResources::hasConfigurationSpaceAgent()'
pci_test/libpci_test.dll.a(d001511.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
pci_resources/libpci_resources.a(PciResources.cpp.obj): In function `PciResources::hasHostCliAgent()':
Z:/pci_resources/src/PciResources.cpp:52: multiple definition of `PciResources::hasHostCliAgent()'
```

None of those functions are declared in other files.

thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the header file you posted. The error is in your other code, or in the way you build your code. Sorry but only possible to guess with the information given.

Comment: `pci_test/libpci_test.dll.a` already has PciResources defined. Don't link with it. Or don't compile `PciResources.cpp` second time.

Comment: It looks like you are compiling the cpp file into two libraries: libci_resources.a and libpic_test.dll.a.  Only one of those libraries should compile the .cpp file.  The other should include the header and link the library that contains the .cpp code.

Comment: @kamilChuk , i am using cmake to compile my project , should i check target_link_libraries in my other translation units ?